# Using Fiona to Convert file geodatabase to PostgreSQL / PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, file-geodatabase, fiona

Is there a way to use Fiona instead of OGR to convert a GDB over to postgresql / postgis within Python?  If so, how or where can I look?  I cannot seem to find this within the Fiona site or by simply Googling around.

Comment: Does [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona) not answer the question -- ie, using gdal from Fiona?

Comment: @John Barça    I'm not sure I follow you.  I can open up a file via Fiona.  I can parse through layers using Fiona.  What I'm not certain of is a graceful way to CONVERT things to postgresql / postgis.  I'm trying to remove OGR calls within Python to be strictly done via Fiona (or so I thought).  Can this be done?  I thought it should be since Fiona is based off of OGR.

Answer (score 2):

Fiona does not currently connect to PostgreSQL/PostGIS as [shown here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/a6ed5b2e6972e4dad438b85e6f4b4ac8db1154c6/fiona/drvsupport.py#L110), and sort-of [documented here](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#rules-of-thumb).

OGR is still a useful tool for PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and other spatial databases.

Comment: Thanks... I wasn't looking to connect... just convert... but maybe you're saying connecting is part of the conversion process?  I was just trying to utilize Fiona as much as possible since it's simply an OGR package for Python.

Comment: Yes, you must connect to a data source to do anything. In other words, Fiona (at present) does not work with PostGIS, as it is a subset of the functionality provided by OGR.

Answer (score 1):

Fiona works with GeoJSON and postgis can produce GeoJSON geometries with `ST_AsGeoJSON(wkbgeometry)` which you can wrap with other (non-geometry) properties to produce a `FeatureCollection`. I just figured that out for postgis use with rasterstats. You can do `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` to go the other way.

No OGR needed because you can do this with a plain vanilla database connection (e.g. psycopg2 in python).

Code snippet:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(connString)
if not conn:
    print("No connection established")
    sys.exit(1)

curs = conn.cursor()

sql = """SELECT id, ST_Area(wkb_geometry), ST_Perimeter(wkb_geometry), ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry)::json 
from spatial_db_table
"""

curs.execute(sql)

features = { "type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "features": [{"type": "feature", "geometry": f[3], "properties": {"id": int(f[0]), "area": float(f[1]), "perimeter": float(f[2])}} for f in curs.fetchall()]} 

with rasterio.open('my_raster.tif') as src:
        affine = src.transform
        array = src.read(1)

zs = zonal_stats(features, array, affine=affine, stats=["count", "mean", "std", "min", "max", "percentile_25", "percentile_50", "percentile_75"], prefix="", nodata=0, geojson_out=True)

print(zs)
```