# FileGDBAPI.dll not registering in Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, gdal, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

*I installed GDAL via wheel (32 bit).  Added it to my system path. Also added an environment variable GDAL_DRIVER_PATH pointing at my gdalplugins folder (on my system, C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins). Rebooted.
At the prompt I tested it by typing
    gdalinfo --help-general
I received this:
    ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins\ogr_FileGDB.dll
    126: The specified module could not be found.
It repeated this error twice.
Yet when I listed directory contents of C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins, I see two files:
ogr_FileGDB.dll and FileGDBAPI.dll (This is the Esri FGDB API dll I pasted in there)
I do notice that ogr_FileGDB.dll is much smaller than the Esri driver.  The ogr one is 181KB, whereas the Esri dll is 9,502KB.
What gives, any ideas?*

**UPDATE:** I am reopening this question because I have followed all of the directions in the listed answer, and I still cannot get the FileGDBAPI.dll to register as an available driver.  Here is what I've done to this point:

1. Followed all the instructions in [How to add support for FileGDB (Esri file gdb API) driver in fiona?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona)
2. Ensured I have a GDAL_DRIVER_PATH environment variable and that it is pointing to `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo`
3. Ensured I have `C:\Python\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo` in my PATH.
4. Ensured I have the FGDB API v. 1.3 (MSVC 2008), 32-bit DLL sitting in the `C:\Python\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo` folder.
5. I installed Boundless Desktop 1.0, but its components do not have any presence in my PATH, PYTHONPATH or GDAL_DRIVER_PATH variables.
6. I have pip installed the GDAL 32-bit wheel for 2.1.3, but when I put in `ogrinfo --version` it yields `GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25` which is incorrect - even though the only pointers for anything GDAL in my environment variables is pointing to the Python27\ArcGIS10.5 install.
7. `ogrinfo --formats` does not give me an error, but it simply fails to find the FileGDB driver.

Comment: See [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193426/2856). ogr_FileGDB.dll should be in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins. FileGDBAPI.dll should be in a directory that is in your Windows PATH (not your PYTHONPATH), I suggest the same directory as the gdalXX.dll, C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\osgeo (XX is version number, i.e gdal111.dll, gdal21.dll) It doesn't go in the gdalplugins directory.