# Geopandas: Write layer back into GeoDataBase

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, fiona, geopandas, pandas

I use geopandas (which uses fiona) to read a GeoDataBase layer (using driver="OpenFileGDB") into a geodataframe for easy manipulation.

`read_shp = gpd.read_file(GDB_file, layer=layer_choice)`

That works well. I then rearrange the columns and do some data manipulation until I am happy with the data.

BUT I have no idea or if it is possible to write that geodataframe back into the GeoDataBase?

I tried:
`read_shp.to_file(GDB_file, layer=layer_choice)`
But that just creates a new shapefile in the wrong place.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7):

As with Fiona where you can specify the driver when you save a layer, you can do the same thing with GeoPandas ([Writing Spatial Data](http://geopandas.org/io.html))

> GeoDataFrames can be exported to many different standard formats using the GeoDataFrame.to_file() method. For a full list of supported formats, type import fiona; fiona.supported_drivers.

In my case:

```
fiona.supported_drivers
{'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', ..., 'FileGDB': 'raw',...}
```

- The [OpenFileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html) driver is Read-only ('r', provides only read access to File Geodatabases)
- If you want read and write access, you need to use the [FileGDB driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) ('raw')

If the driver is not installed, a solution is given in [How to add support for FileGDB (Esri file gdb API) driver in fiona?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona)

```
layer.to_file("result.gdf",driver="FileGDB")
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Took a while to realize that I could get the FileGDB.dll file and installation through GIS Internals, rather than the ESRI route (which didn't work for me). Perhaps another thing to add is that you can overwrite a layer in a GDB, simply by adding specifying the layer target `layer.to_file("result.gdb", layer="layer_name", driver="FileGDB")`.

Comment: For that I get `Unsupported Driver`

Answer (score -3):

Have you seen [this page](https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/cdi/pandas.DataFrame+to+ArcGIS+Table) from the USGS? 
It describes how to move tabular data back to a gdb using ArcPy. You might be able to tweak that...

It looks like geopandas does not write to GDB, due to that being an Esri proprietary format. You can run

```
import fiona pprint(fiona.supported_drivers)
```

to get the supported formats geopandas can write to:

```
 'ARCGEN': 'r',
 'AeronavFAA': 'r',
 'BNA': 'raw',
 'DGN': 'raw',
 'DXF': 'raw',
 'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw',
 'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw',
 'GPX': 'raw',
 'GeoJSON': 'rw',
 'Idrisi': 'r',
 'MapInfo File': 'raw',
 'OpenFileGDB': 'r',
 'PCIDSK': 'r',
 'SEGY': 'r',
 'SUA': 'r'
```

Would it be feasible for your process to export to a shapefile and then use arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion to bring that into your GDB?