# Is there a way to install FileGDB driver after QGIS has been installed?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, qgis-3

I have QGIS 3.2 installed (Windows 7 64-bit), and I need to be able to read and write to Esri file geodatabases.

I have read the thread [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis), which explains how to install the necessary FileGDB driver during a fresh install of QGIS; however, I would like to install the FileGDB driver for my *existing* install of QGIS.

So, my question is:

**Is there a way to install the FileGDB driver *after* QGIS has been installed?**

*p.s. If this were on my personal computer at home, I'd just do a fresh install. As it stands, it took me a few years of pestering my IT folks to even get them to allow an install of QGIS on my machine as a "test case", so the fewer hoops I have to ask them to jump through to get QGIS to meet all of our needs, like read/write to File GDB, the better!*

Comment: You should at lest be able to read them without installing any driver. What happens when you try: Layer-Add Layer-Add vector layer-Choose Directory, OpenFileGDB and the .gdb

Comment: Yes, I'm able to read file geodatabases with no problem. As I stated, I need to also be able to write to file geodatabases. It's my understanding that to do so, I need to have the FileGDB driver installed rather than the default OpenFileGDB driver.

Comment: The very bottom post of this link, shows the two files you need and where to copy each file for FileGDBapi (esri r/w) support in Qgis. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install gdal-filegdb on an existing QGIS (not installed with osgeo4w):
close QGIS,
run osgeo4w shell from QGIS 3.x program group as an administrator.

[image]

Run setup with -l option indicating the gdalplugins directory (under QGIS/bin) and -P option gdal-filegdb.
You will be prompted for setup options (like qgis osgeo4w install). Select advanced and in the lib section be sure to have gdal-filegdb checked.
Run QGIS, you will get the ESRI file gdb option on loading vector layers->directory.
[image]

Comment: Since I had my IT people already do a clean install (with gdal-filegdb selected, see my comment below), I can't test this out. It looks like the way to accomplish what I was trying to do (install the gdal-filegdb driver post-QGIS install), so I'm marking it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had my IT department do a clean install of QGIS, following the instructions in the aforementioned thread [Installing File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

At this point, I'm not sure if there's a way to install the FileGDB driver after installing QGIS, so this seems like the only workaround.

EDIT: Atilio's answer above achieves what I was originally trying to do (install the driver after QGIS was installed), so I've marked it as the answer. A clean install will still work, of course, but it's not optimal.