# ESRI FIleGDB API dll failure: ogr2ogr can't recognize File GDB as driver type

Tags: gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, esri-geodatabase, dll

I have been trying this for a day or two now, and I have followed the instructions listed here:
 **[How to add support for FileGDB (Esri file gdb API) driver in fiona](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona)**
 
but for the life of me I can't seem to get ogr2ogr to recognize FileGDB as a driver. My end goal is to append shapefiles to an already exisiting .gdb file on my local machine. I have set all the environment variables to the seemingly appropriate locations (GDAL_DATA, GDAL_DRIVER_PATH, PROJ_LIB, etc.), and all my dll files seem to be in the correct location. I am using Python 3.7.4 via Anaconda3 command console. Furthermore, I am using Windows 10.